# How can I count the number of times a particular number occurs within a column?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'd like to know how many times numbers between 1000-10,000 occur in a column. For example, the number 1000 occurs 5 times, the number 1010 occurs 6 times, 1100 occurs 4 times, etc. Right now, I'm manually creating a column that lists each number from 1000-10,000 and another column that uses the COUNTIF function to find how many of that number exist.

[Sample spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBeV1.png)

Is there a formula that could produce a summary of the number of times each number between 1000-10,000 occurs so I don't have to do it manually?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You could make a Pivot Table if you need the count or frequency of **each value**.  To get the overall summary:

```
=COUNTIF(A1:A10750,"<10001")-COUNTIF(A1:A10750,"<1000")
```

If you like your current table, but want to avoid the manual labor, try this short macro:

```
Sub tablemaker()
    For i = 1000 To 10000
        Cells(i - 999, "B").Value = i
    Next i

    Range("C1").Formula = "=COUNTIF(A$1:A$10750,B1)"
    Range("C1").AutoFill Destination:=Range("C1:C9001")
End Sub
```

Comment: Was there a reason you didn't use COUNTIFS?

Comment: @Jeeped  I just forgot about it.

Answer (score 0):

*There are various methods to attain the goal, and I would like to suggest few:*

**Method 1:**

It comprise,

- Unique list of Numbers.
- The `COUNTIF` worksheet function.

[image]

- An array (CSE) formula in cell `E41`:

  ```
   {=IFERROR(INDEX($D$41:$D$56, MATCH(0,COUNTIF($E$40:E40, $D$41:$D$56), 0)),"")}
  ```
- Finish the formula with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** & fill down.
- Enter this formula in cell `F41`:

  ```
   =IF(COUNTIF(D$41:D$56,E41)=0,"",COUNTIF(D$41:D$56,E41))
  ```

---

**Method 2:**

It comprise,

- Unique list of Numbers.
- The `FREQUENCY` worksheet function.
- Cell `E41` has same array formula what has been shown above.

[image]

- An Array (CSE) Formual in cell `G41`:

  ```
   {=IF(FREQUENCY(D$41:D$56,E$41:E$43)=0, "",FREQUENCY(D$41:D$56,E$41:E$43))}
  ```

**How it works:**

- Enter above shown formula in cell `G41` then fill down till required, press `F2`, and finish with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**.

---

**Method 3:**

*It's creating a Pivot Table.*

[image]

- Use Numbers in Row.
- Apply Count of Numbers for Value.

---

**Method 4:**

It comprise,

- Dynamic Named Range.
- And `COUNTIFS` worksheet formula.

[image]

**How it works:**

- Select range `D41:D56`.
- Press **Ctrl+F3**

[image]

- Provide a suitable Name (I've used `MYNumber`).
- Use this formula for reference.

  ```
   =OFFSET(Sheet1!$D$41, 0, 0, COUNTA(Sheet1!$D:$D), 1)
  ```
- An array (CSE) Formula in cell `J41`:

  ```
   {=INDEX(MYNumber,MATCH(TRUE,MYNumber<>"",0))}
  ```

*Finish with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter***.

- Formula in cell `J42`:

  `=LOOKUP(2,1/(MYNumber<>0),MYNumber)`
- Final formula in `J44`:

  ```
    =COUNTIFS(MYNumber,">="&J41,MYNumber,"<="&J42)
  ```

*As soon you add or remove new value to range `MYNumber`,  `D41` downwards, Excel will automatically update `Firs`t & `Last` Value in cell `J41` and in `J42`.*

---

**N.B.**

*You need to adjust cell references in above shown formula as needed.*